# XAMPP MySQL module won't start

Tags: mysql, module, xampp

Thanks for taking a look.

I get a weird error when trying to start MySQL in XAMPP. Or rather no error at all. This is the MySQL Error Log:

```
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-05-08 19:22:43 11c8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 12182744
**2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [ERROR] Aborting**

2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Binlog end
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-05-08 19:22:43 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12182754
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-05-08 19:22:45 5736 [Note]
```

XAMPP client outputs the familiar:

```
19:22:43  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
19:22:45  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
19:22:45  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
19:22:45  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
19:22:45  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
19:22:45  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
19:22:45  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
19:22:45  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
19:22:45  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is a netstat -an command in command prompt as suggested by Robert Rozas. Port 3306 is not in use:

```
C:\Users\LarsAndreas>netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17500          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49163          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:52077          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:60643        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:60646        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19872        127.0.0.1:55480        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55398        127.0.0.1:55400        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55400        127.0.0.1:55398        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55480        127.0.0.1:19872        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.233:56162    157.56.124.47:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:56216    173.194.69.125:5222    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:56223    80.239.208.193:1119    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:56283    173.194.71.188:5228    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:56321    108.160.163.104:80     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:59355    198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60636    81.167.38.82:80        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60640    157.56.17.247:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60641    157.56.17.247:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60642    157.56.17.247:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60649    198.252.206.140:443    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60650    198.252.206.140:443    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60651    198.252.206.140:443    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60652    68.232.35.121:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60653    68.232.35.121:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60654    68.232.35.121:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60656    107.20.242.0:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60657    107.20.242.0:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60659    2.21.203.120:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60661    54.243.128.120:80      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60662    173.194.32.8:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60663    173.194.32.3:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.233:60664    173.194.71.84:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:554               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2869              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3587              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:10243             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49152             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49153             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49154             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49155             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49156             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49163             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:52077             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [fe80::e867:45b:9ed3:4401%2]:445  [fe80::e867:45b:9ed3:4401%2]:55319  E
STABLISHED
  TCP    [fe80::e867:45b:9ed3:4401%2]:55319  [fe80::e867:45b:9ed3:4401%2]:445  E
STABLISHED
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1900           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5004           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5005           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:6771           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:17500          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50319          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:51618          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:52077          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55125          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:59801          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:64084          *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:44301        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:53154        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:60796        *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.233:137      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.233:138      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.233:1900     *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.233:53153    *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.233:60795    *:*
  UDP    [::]:3540              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5004              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5005              *:*
  UDP    [::]:50320             *:*
  UDP    [::]:51619             *:*
  UDP    [::]:52077             *:*
  UDP    [::]:55126             *:*
  UDP    [::]:59803             *:*
  UDP    [::]:64085             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:53152            *:*
  UDP    [fe80::e867:45b:9ed3:4401%2]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::e867:45b:9ed3:4401%2]:53151  *:*
```

Anyone ever encountered this? Any help is sincerely appreciated, as I'm in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Deleting this files:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1
```

Start XAMP again and see if it works

Comment: I tried this but they were just recreated, new log entries specified this: `2014-05-08 20:27:32 13192 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=12182754`. Thanks for the suggestion though, got any more? :P

Comment: open a cmd and type `netstat -an` and see if the port 3306 is used by another process

Comment: I have updated my question with the results, and it seems that it is not in use!

Comment: Uninstall XAMPP, delete the folders, clean the registry and reinstall it again

Comment: That did it bro! Must've been something corrupt, as I've recently deleted XAMPP and tried out WAMP, just for fun, and then reinstalled XAMPP. Thank you for your help, Robert Rozas :)

Comment: Feel free to ask...we are here to help ;)